# angularjs $parse string to a "controller as" method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I parse `foo.callbacke` to point to `timerController.callbacke` method?

```
<div ng-app="timerApp" ng-controller="timerController as foo">
<div ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4]">
    <div watcher="{'seconds': 'foo.callbacke'}">
        {{seconds}}
    </div>
</div>
```

If you prefer: http://jsfiddle.net/e86e05a1/ (open console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You this would be available inside your directive `scope` thats why directive can access controller method by $scope it self so there is no need to pass `controllerAs` alias here. Only pass method name here. Instead of accessing the function by index anotation try using `$eval` on `scope`.

**Note**

> You should use $observe unless you have interpolation on attribute
>   like `{{something}}`

**Markup**

```
<div watcher="{'seconds': 'callbacke'}">
```

**Code**

```
angular.forEach(new_watchers, function(callback, k) {
     watchers.push($scope.$watch(k, function() {
         return $scope.$eval(callback)($scope, $element);
     }));
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e86e05a1/2/)

Comment: hmm that was really nice. $eval did the job very well. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a function reference to directive in that way. What you can do it create a isolated scope in the directive and map the parent controller's function to the directive scope using `=`. Try this.

**Html**

```
<div callbacke="callbacke" watcher>
    {{seconds}}
</div>
```

**JS**

```
.directive('watcher', ['$compile', '$parse', function($compile, $parse) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            callbacke: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function($scope, $element, attrs) {
            var watchers = [];
            console.log($scope.callbacke);
            ...
            ...
        }]
        ...
        ...
    };
}]);
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/e86e05a1/1/

Comment: Yes, you're right. I could do this way. but I'm avoiding scope isolation since I want watcher directive to being reusable even on elements that have already isolated scopes. So this way I dont need to create extra elements in the view just to bind watcher directive.